# SQL select string between known identical characters

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I have code which selects the string between the first and second '/' in a typical string which may look like this:

> 2014-Ceilings/Ceilings/Repair/Asbestos/Supalux

The following code correctly returns the value 'Ceilings' in the above example.

```
SELECT 
REPLACE (LEFT(SUBSTRING(ElementPath,CHARINDEX
            ('/',ElementPath)+1,LEN(ElementPath)),CHARINDEX
        ('/',SUBSTRING(ElementPath, CHARINDEX
                ('/',ElementPath)+1,LEN(ElementPath)))),'/','')
FROM K2_Master.dbo.tbElement
```

How can I amend it to select the string between the second and third '/' to return the value 'Repair'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this little trick may work :

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)= '2014-Ceilings/Ceilings/Repair/Asbestos/Supalux'

SET @String = '<N>' + Replace(@String, '/', '</N><N>')
              + '</N>'

SELECT c.value('/N[1]', 'varchar(30)'),
       c.value('/N[2]', 'varchar(30)'),
       c.value('/N[3]', 'varchar(30)')
FROM   (SELECT Cast(@String AS XML)) t(c) 

SELECT c1.value('.', 'varchar(30)')
FROM   (SELECT CAST(@String AS XML)) t(c)
       CROSS APPLY c.nodes('/N') AS t1(c1) 

SELECT value
FROM   (SELECT c1.value('.', 'varchar(30)') AS value,
               ROW_NUMBER()
                 OVER(
                   ORDER BY (SELECT 1))     rn
        FROM   (SELECT Cast(@String AS XML)) t(c)
               CROSS APPLY c.nodes('/N') AS t1(c1)) temp
WHERE  rn = 3
```

In your case

```
SELECT c.value('/N[1]', 'varchar(30)'),
       c.value('/N[2]', 'varchar(30)'),
       c.value('/N[3]', 'varchar(30)')
FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<N>' + Replace( Replace (ElementPath, '/', '</N><N>'),'&','&amp;')
                     + '</N>' AS XML)
        FROM   K2_Master.dbo.tbElement) t(c)
```

Comment: Good answer..I haven't seen this approach.

Comment: Try now I have replaced `&` character too.

Answer (score 1):

I chased your question, and reached a lengthy result..

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(40) = '2014-Ceilings/Ceilings/Repair/Asbestos/Supalux'

SELECT      @a
            ,LEFT(
            SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@a,CHARINDEX('/',@a,1)+1,LEN(@a)),CHARINDEX('/',SUBSTRING(@a,CHARINDEX('/',@a,1)+1,LEN(@a)),1)+1,LEN(SUBSTRING(@a,CHARINDEX('/',@a,1)+1,LEN(@a)))),
            CHARINDEX('/',SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@a,CHARINDEX('/',@a,1)+1,LEN(@a)),CHARINDEX('/',SUBSTRING(@a,CHARINDEX('/',@a,1)+1,LEN(@a)),1)+1,LEN(SUBSTRING(@a,CHARINDEX('/',@a,1)+1,LEN(@a)))),1) - 1
            )
```

Result:

### [image]

*Answer to you comment.*

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)= '2014-Ceilings/Ceilings/Repair/Asbestos/Supalux',
        @value INT = 2
DECLARE @itra INT = 1

WHILE @itra <= @value
BEGIN 
    SET @String = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,CHARINDEX('/',@String,1)+1,LEN(@String)))
    --SELECT @String
    SET @itra = @itra + 1
END 

SELECT LEFT(@String, CHARINDEX('/',@String,1) - 1)
```

Give the position of '/' as `@value` and see the result. For the above sql, the result is `Repair`. If you give `@value = 3,` result is `Asbestos`

Comment: This works fine thanks. Would you mind showing how I could amend it further to choose the string between the 3rd and 4th instance of '/'